# Move only a button when android soft keyboard is displayed

Tags: android, resize, android-softkeyboard

I'm currently working with the soft keyboard and I try to resize the layout when the keyboard is shown.

When the keyboard appears, I want the button in the bottom to be moved above the keyboard, but I don't want the ViewPager to stretch its fragment layouts (it is what happens with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` ).

Does anybody know if there is a way to resize the button AND to block the viewpager (and its fragments) in the same time while the soft keyboard is shown?

XML of the layout with the button to move:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:elevation="@dimen/actionBarElevation"
            app:contentInsetEnd="4dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="4dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="4dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="4dp">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:text="@string/cigarette_former_consumption"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/actionBarTitleSize"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_filter_button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/actionBarIconSize"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/actionBarFilterButtonPadding"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/actionBarFilterButtonPadding"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/actionBarFilterButtonPadding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/actionBarFilterButtonPadding"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/toolbar_icon_filter"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/baseSideMargin"
                android:text="@string/toolbar_filter_button_label"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:alpha="0"
                android:enabled="false"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/cig_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:background="@drawable/switch_background_checked"
                android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                android:text="@string/next_label"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot without keyboard:
[image]

Screenshot with keyboard:
[image]

Comment: `setOnFocusChangeListener` on `EditText` to trigger the function to move the button's position.

Comment: I can't call the function that resizes the layout, the option is specified in the manifest, the resize is automatic, when the keyboard is displayed

Comment: Just clarifying what you need. You don't want to resize the layout, right? So you can move the button over the layout using a FrameLayout.

Comment: Didn't think about that. But I'm not used to FrameLayouts except for holding fragments. Can you explain what you mean by "moving the button with a FrameLayout"?